# Firebase: Android Ordering by child count

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to order posts by the popularity of the car that is child of each post, followed by timestamp, ideally on the server side.

For example if:
 - posts p1 and p2 have child car b7
 - posts p3, p4, and p5 have child car b8 
 - post p6 has child car b6

the expected result is:

1: p5
2: p4
3: p3
4: p2
5: p1
6: p6

Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Thanks Frank, I had already looked at the documentation but can't work out how to do it on the server side. i just can't work out how to order by a child count. I guess it's similar to ordering the Firebase FriendlyPix demo app posts by number of likes for each post.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called an aggregation, which groups items and operates on their values in total.  SQL has support for aggregate functions, such as count, sum, and avg used with a "group by" clause.  However, Firebase Realtime Database does not offer this type of querying.

For your data, if you want to effectively count posts grouped by some property, you would have to create a separate data structure to maintain the counts that you want, and update that structure any time the posts collection changes.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, however I'm not quite sure what the data structure should be. Can you give me an example please?